# Will the hats be permanent

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I was wondering if the hats that I gained during this period will remain or I have them only during Christmas.

If it has an end, when does Winter Bash and hats period ends?

Comment: Did u read the [FAQ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: The definitive answer to this question is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSWiMoO8zNE.

Answer (score 1):

No, hats are not permanent. Winterbash 2016 will end on January 8th, 2017. From the [announcement blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/?cb=1):

> Starting today through the **end of the day on 8 January 2017**, you'll be able to earn and **wear hats** (and possibly accessories) for performing various things you already do across the Stack Exchange network.

(emphasis mine)

Also, from the [FAQ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What happens after January 8th?
>
> After January 8th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

Answer (score 0):

No, site will turn to normal after January 8th, 2017 According to [FAQ](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq):

> After January 8th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear.
>   This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent
>   addition to the site.

Podcast mentioned one day extra i.e. January 9th,

[From podcast](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Stack-Overflow-Podcast-97-Where-did-you-get-that-hat/?cb=1):

> There are 28 known hats as well as a few secret hats that users will
>   have to find on their own. Winter Bash runs December 19 - January 9th
>   on (almost) all Stack Exchange sites.